# Node.js : Write html with Eventsource

Tags: html, node.js, eventsource

I'm trying to solve a problem with my code here. I have an node.js file (serverside) and an index2.html (clientside). I'm trying to read on serverside the html file and write the concent.

Serverside:

```
    switch (pathname) {

    case '/a':

        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

        fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, index) {

            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }

        res.write(index + "\n\n");
        res.end();

        });
```

Clientside (index2.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="status"></p>

<script>

const source = new EventSource("");

if(typeof(EventSource) === "undefined") {
    source.onopen = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Connection lost...";
        };

} else {
    source.onopen = function(event) {
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Connection opened...";
        };
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I won't get any connection text. Not lost or opened?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Requesting single items of data (the contents of index2.html in your example) then closing the connection, is not what EventSource is designed for; instead it is designed to keep a socket open, so that the server can push out more data to the client in future. You should be using a simple AJAX connection here.

But, you should still be able to use `EventSource`. The first fix is that it needs its own mime-type, do not specify text/html.

```
res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/event-stream" });
```

Second, the SSE protocol means each block of data is prefixed with "data:" and suffixed with two LFs. So your line should look like this:

```
res.write("data:" + index + "\n\n");
```

You obviously need to make sure `index` does not contain any `\n`. As it is HTML, you could convert them all to spaces (unless you have `<pre>` blocks!). A more general solution is to wrap any data in a JSON object, and then un-pack that JSON on the client.

Finally, the client-side code in your question has a `""` typo when giving the URL. I'm assuming this was a typo just when writing the question! But if it is in your original, that would also stop everything working :-)
Use the developer tools in your browser to catch those kind of issues (and to see the SSE data passing back and forth, so you can also eliminate other problems, such as firewalls).